# C++ initialize variable based on condition

Tags: c++, initialization, conditional-statements

I am currently trying to figure out how to initialize variables based on conditions. So this is the current code that I want to modify:

```
int dimsOut[4];
dimsOut[0] = data->nDataVar();
dimsOut[1] = dims[0];
dimsOut[2] = dims[1];
dimsOut[3] = dims[2];

const size_t dataSize = data->primType().getTypeSize() * dimsOut[0] * dimsOut[1] * dimsOut[2] * dimsOut[3];
```

Since this is part of a giant project (mostly C++98 with some parts of C++03) I want to try to modify as less as possible to avoid any problems in the rest of the code.
So what I want to do is simply in case `data->nDataVar()` returns 1 that the code above executes and in case it returns something else it should 
basically do this

> ```
> int dimsOut[3];
> dimsOut[0] = data->nDataVar();
> dimsOut[1] = dims[0];
> dimsOut[2] = dims[1];
>
> const size_t dataSize = data->primType().getTypeSize() * dimsOut[0] * dimsOut[1] * dimsOut[2];
> ```

I am aware that it is not possible to use if-statements since the variables would go out of scope.

Edit: I solved my problem now. It is not beautiful, but it does what it is supposed to do.

Edit2: small change

```
    int decide_dimension = data->nDataVar();
    std::vector<int> dimsOut;
    dimsOut.resize(3);
    dimsOut[0] = dims[0];
    dimsOut[1] = dims[1];
    dimsOut[2] = dims[2];
    if (decide_dimension != 1)
    {
        dimsOut.push_back(data->nDataVar());
    }

const size_t dataSize = data->primType().getTypeSize() * dimsOut[0] * dimsOut[1] * dimsOut[2] * ((decide_dimension == 1) ? 1 : dimsOut[3]);
```

Comment: Does `dimsOut` *have* to be an array? It can't be a `std::vector`? Or possibly a pointer to a dynamically allocated "array"?

Comment: And how are you using `dimsOut` *after* the code you show? Is it used at all?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. If you want `dimsOut` to be the size of either 3 or 4 and not affect the rest of the code, what the rest of the code expects it to be, what size 3 or 4?

Comment: You can't use `if`, but you *can* use the ternary operator (`?:`).

Comment: Have you heard of a `for` loop??

Comment: Why can't the size of `dimsOut` be just 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ternary or conditional operator. The basic form is:

```
condition ? valueIfTrue : valueIfFalse
```

Example:

```
const char* x = (SomeFunction() == 0) ? "is null" : "is not null";
```

When `SomeFunction()` returns 0, `x` is initialised with "`is null`", otherwise
with "`is not null`".

Comment: What this has to do with the question?

Comment: @KillzoneKid If you are referring to a second statement, I assume it is meant as an example to demonstrate the use of a ternary operator.

Comment: @Ron OP's question is confusing. Do they want to make `dimsOut` of size of 3 or 4 based on condition? Then this answer has nothing to do with it. However if OP wants to change `const size_t dataSize` value based on condition, using ternary operator would make sense, but then this should be reflected in the answer for clarity.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem with a variation of different things.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is not possible. The only thing you can do, is to initialize them with a ternary as suggested or move the initialization into a `if` block and leave the declaration out.

Comment: I'd say without further clarification from OP it is unclear what they actually trying to achieve

Comment: I think, he wants a conditional scope wide declaration at run-time. This is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You say you are modifying an existing old project. In that case it makes sense to keep changes minimal.

However, you can't define the size of a static array at run time. If you want, you can keep the array as it currently is and make sure you don't use the 4th element when data->nDataVar() != 1.

Then:

```
const size_t dataSize = data->primType().getTypeSize() * dimsOut[0] * dimsOut[1] * dimsOut[2] * (data->nDataVar() != 1 ? 1 : dimsOut[3]);
```

It's worth mentioning the dimsOut array seems completely unnecessary to calculate the value of dataSize, but who knows what else your code is doing with it. If it is only used inside a single function/method then you could easily replace it with something else, such as std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit confusing, or rather not enough information was provided.  It is not clear if the `dimsOut[]` variable is needed elsewhere. In case it is used ONLY for the computation of `dataSize`, you can use directly the `dims[]` array and do:

```
int typeSize = data->primType().getTypeSize() * data->nDataVar();
int dimension = dims[0] * dims[1] * ((condition) ? dims[2] : 1);
const size_t dataSize = typeSize * dimension;
```

In case that dimsOut is used elsewhere, then you can use the first block modifying the dimsOut[3] assignment with the ternary operator:

```
int dimsOut[4];
dimsOut[0] = data->nDataVar();
dimsOut[1] = dims[0];
dimsOut[2] = dims[1];
dimsOut[3] = (condition) ? dims[2] : 1;

const size_t dataSize = data->primType().getTypeSize() * dimsOut[0] * dimsOut[1] * dimsOut[2] * dimsOut[3];
```